# Can't have access to admin console in glassfish 3

Tags: glassfish

I have started glassfish server in netbeans, but cant't have access to admin console through web brouser on localhost:4848
The log of start up process:

```
21.01.2011 18:48:34 com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain main
INFO: Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
Welcome to Felix
================
INFO: Perform lazy SSL initialization for the listener 'http-listener-1'
INFO: Perform lazy SSL initialization for the listener 'http-listener-2'
INFO: Perform lazy SSL initialization for the listener 'admin-listener'
INFO: Starting Grizzly Framework 1.9.18-k - Fri Jan 21 18:48:37 EET 2011
INFO: The Admin Console is already installed, but not yet loaded.
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.18-k started in: 219ms listening on port 8181
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.18-k started in: 203ms listening on port 4848
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.18-k started in: 235ms listening on port 8080
INFO: Starting Grizzly Framework 1.9.18-k - Fri Jan 21 18:48:37 EET 2011
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.18-k started in: 906ms listening on port 3700
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.18-k started in: 891ms listening on port 7676
INFO: GlassFish v3 (74.2) startup time : Felix(2422ms) startup services(1890ms) total(4312ms)
INFO: javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.classLoaderProvider = org.glassfish.weld.WeldActivator$GlassFishClassLoaderProvider@1fa2b3e
INFO: Hibernate Validator bean-validator-3.0-JBoss-4.0.2
INFO: Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.
INFO: Binding RMI port to *:8686
INFO: JMXStartupService: Started JMXConnector, JMXService URL = service:jmx:rmi://localhost:8686/jndi/rmi://localhost:8686/jmxrmi
INFO: Using com.sun.enterprise.transaction.jts.JavaEETransactionManagerJTSDelegate as the delegate
INFO: Perform lazy SSL initialization for the listener 'http-listener-1'
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.18-k started in: 0ms listening on port 8080
INFO: [Thread[GlassFish Kernel Main Thread,5,main]] started
INFO: {felix.fileinstall.poll (ms) = 5000, felix.fileinstall.dir = C:\Program Files\sges-v3\glassfish\modules\autostart, felix.fileinstall.debug = 1, felix.fileinstall.bundles.new.start = true, felix.fileinstall.tmpdir = C:\DOCUME~1\Admin\LOCALS~1\Temp\fileinstall-6018388012782185995, felix.fileinstall.filter = null}
INFO: Perform lazy SSL initialization for the listener 'http-listener-2'
INFO: {felix.fileinstall.poll (ms) = 5000, felix.fileinstall.dir = C:\Program Files\sges-v3\glassfish\domains\domain1\autodeploy\bundles, felix.fileinstall.debug = 1, felix.fileinstall.bundles.new.start = true, felix.fileinstall.tmpdir = C:\DOCUME~1\Admin\LOCALS~1\Temp\fileinstall-570365091622749624, felix.fileinstall.filter = null}
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.18-k started in: 16ms listening on port 8181
INFO: Updating configuration from org.apache.felix.fileinstall-autodeploy-bundles.cfg
INFO: Installed C:\Program Files\sges-v3\glassfish\modules\autostart\org.apache.felix.fileinstall-autodeploy-bundles.cfg
INFO: {felix.fileinstall.poll (ms) = 5000, felix.fileinstall.dir = C:\Program Files\sges-v3\glassfish\domains\domain1\autodeploy\bundles, felix.fileinstall.debug = 1, felix.fileinstall.bundles.new.start = true, felix.fileinstall.tmpdir = C:\DOCUME~1\Admin\LOCALS~1\Temp\fileinstall--7403987252271825379, felix.fileinstall.filter = null}
```

How can i have access to console?

edited:
It is available on https://localhost:4848
How i can change it to http://localhost:4848

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a thousand words... and then some...
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue. It worked/browsed earlier.
I felt that there is some goof up in internet explorer in Windows 7.
I just changed to the latest version of Google Chrome, and it just worked.

Comment: Not a exact answer. Changing the version is one of the possible answer, but it's not always feasible.